# WCF and multiple Callback Contract possible

Tags: wcf

i am newbie in WCF.i was looking for wayout of multiple Callback Contract possible or not like below

```
[ServiceContract (
CallbackContract = typeof (CallbackContract_1),
CallbackContract = typeof (CallbackContract_2),
CallbackContract = typeof (CallbackContract_3))
]
public interface SomeWcfContract {}
```

i was searching google and found way out that was like

```
interface ICallbackContract1
{...}

interface ICallbackContract2 : ICallbackContract1
{...}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract1))]
interface IMyBaseContract
{...}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract2))]
interface IMySubContract : IMyBaseContract
{...}

or

interface ICallbackContract1
{...}
interface ICallbackContract2
{...}
interface ICallbackContract3 : ICallbackContract2,ICallbackContract1
{...}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract1))]
interface IMyBaseContract1
{...}
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract2))]
interface IMyBaseContract2
{...}
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackContract3))]
interface IMySubContract : IMyBaseContract1,IMyBaseContract2
{...}
```

i just need to know is there any other way out for multiple callback contract. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple callback contracts for a single service contract (it's a 1:1 relationship, where the callback contract can be null). That alternative (using multiple "forward" contracts, each one with its own callback contract), as you found, should work, although I haven't tried (you can write a simple program to test that).